# ResponseStatusException не возвращает сообщение

Tags: spring, исключения

При выбрасывании исключения след код должен возвратить ошибку с соот текстом, как пишут https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<FeedbackDto> get(@RequestHeader(value = "user-token") String userToken) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(feedbackService.getByUserToken(userToken));
    } catch (UserNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User Not Found. Id=" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Проверяю через постман. приходит

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-05T15:53:49.120+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/feedback"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62467065/3212712) для [Spring Boot версии 2.3+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content) надо добавить такое в `application.properties`, чтобы всегда выводилась ошибка:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```